# Laravel 6: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST Error

Tags: php, laravel-6

I'm new to Laravel 6, and I'm trying to make a edit profile feature but I'm stuck with the error:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST
```

To be honest, I am not sure why i get this error. I have cross checked everything.

ProfileController
update function

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $profile->nickname = $request->input('nickname');
        $profile->name = $request->input('name');
        $profile->birthday = $request->input('birthday');
        $profile->save(); //persist the data
        return redirect()->route('profile.index')->with('info','Profile got saved');
    }
```

My route file:

```
Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@index')->name('profile');

Route::put('/profile/edit/{profile}','ProfileController@update')->name('profile.update');
```

edit.blade.php

```
<form action="{{route('profile.update')}}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PUT')

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="nickname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Brugernavn') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="nickname" type="text" class="form-control @error('nickname') is-invalid @enderror" name="nickname" value="{{ Auth::user()->nickname }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Submit -->
                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
                                    Gem
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: You added spoofing form methods, but Laravel not run `put` action. You should exec `php artisan route:list` to check first matched rule.

Comment: Your routing is incorrect, you targeting wrong route. Check your routes, for edit you have to pass an id, but for the update you have to pass data and id as well, and if you have used `PUT` then your route method will also be `PUT`, if it's `POST` method in your route, then you don't need to use `PUT` method in your form.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: isn't `Route::post` pretty clear? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a usal Laravel offers using 5 methods.

```
GET/contacts, mapped to the index() method and shows contacts list,
GET /contacts/create, mapped to the create() method and shows create form,
POST /contacts, mapped to the store() method and handle create form request,
GET /contacts/{contact}, mapped to the show() method and shows single item,
GET /contacts/{contact}/edit, mapped to the edit() method and shows update form,
PUT/PATCH /contacts/{contact}, mapped to the update() method and handle update form request,
DELETE /contacts/{contact}, mapped to the destroy() method and handle delete form request.
```

You have to change your route.php file

```
Route::put('/profile/edit/{profile}','ProfileController@update')->name('profile.update');
```

And in your form, change action

```
<form action="{{ route('profile.update', Auth::user()->id) }}" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

For more: https://www.techiediaries.com/php-laravel-crud-mysql-tutorial/

Comment: After changing to what you suggested im getting a 404, so i cant find it somehow. Is edit and updated linked to each other?

Comment: Thank you for linking me to the crud tutorial. I got it working. My only concern is the url when i edit? When enter the edit.blade the url is: /profile/16/edit etc, but thats possible to change when using laravel 6? The edit profile is only for user himself, no admin or other users

Comment: Like if i log into another use and enters the url: /profile/16/edit, it shows user id: 17 information, but when trying to edit, its trying to go for id 17, is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

```
You are getting the error because your route expects post and you are using get method

Route::get('/profile/edit','ProfileController@edit')->name('profile.edit');


Route::put('/profile/','ProfileController@update')->name('profile.update');


public function edit() {

return view (edit);
}

public function update() {

//things to update
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your edit.blade.php file  remove

```
 @method('PUT')
```

then your method will be post only

Answer (score 0):

You can set route method any

```
Change Route::post('/profile/edit','ProfileController@update')->name('profile.update'); 
to 
Route::any('/profile/edit','ProfileController@update')->name('profile.update'); change
```

Thanks